# Units of measurement in turn-by-turn navigation

Tags: here-api, heremaps-ios-sdk

I'm using "HERE SDK for iOS" to implement turn-by-turn navigation in my app. I have one issue when I display the distance in GuidanceManeuverView and GuidanceEstimatedArrivalView. All measurements are showing in feet, yards, and miles. However, in US we don’t use yards, but just miles and feet. The only way to configure measurementSystem is `navigationManager.voicePackageMeasurementSystem = .imperialUS` but it only change the voice sentences.

Is there anyway to change units of measurement to **imperialUS**?

Comment: Looks like this is a question for the 3.x HERE SDK for iOS (Premium Edition). Maybe consider to try the newer 4.x Navigate Edition instead: https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-sdk-navigate.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding SDK 3.X (Premium Edition), it is only possible to set the unit for voice guidance. There are two options for achieving your goal:

(1)Implement the conversion on the application side by using the measurement framework from Apple under the hood. Please find the below docs:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/measurementformatter/
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/units_and_measurement

If you are using HERE Mobile SDK UI Kit, then you can get the idea from the sample codes: https://github.com/heremaps/msdkui-ios/blob/3bb9dfc95647f489521b70e2ae5fb0a536cdb589/Documentation/Guides_Examples/MSDKUIPrimer/MSDKUIPrimer/GuidanceViewController.swift#L48

(2)Use SDK 4.x Navigate Edition
https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-sdk-navigate/